# HttpSession, session.getAttribute(), problem

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

I have a problem related to Java servlet sessions. I don't understand why the `getAttribute()` function of the session object is used before `setAttribute();` Here is the code:

```
Vector buylist=(Vector)session.getAttribute("Register");
if (action.equals("del")) {
String del = request.getParameter("deli");
int d = (new Integer(del)).intValue();
buylist.removeElementAt(d);
}
session.setAttribute("Register", buylist);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Ask the co-worker who wrote it. Or do you guys communicate via stackoverflow? :-)

Comment: Could be he reading tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `Register` attribute may be set from some other  place (like. from jsp(in bad case),Servlet or Filter . . )

Answer (score 1):

This code intends to save back the modified vector represented by Register session attribute.
However you dont need to set the attribute back even after some elements are removed or added because its the reference anyways thats stored in session and any changes to it are essentially being applied to the *same* object.

Answer (score 0):

The only explanation I can think of is: first of all you you retrieve the vector, then make the change and after store it back into session object.

Answer (score 0):

The code is either broken or the `setAttribute()` is futile.

If you get a mutable container (like a list or a vector) from the session, then it's not necessary to put it again into the session. It's the equivalent of this code:

```
 session.setAttribute("Register", buylist);
 session.setAttribute("Register", buylist);
 session.setAttribute("Register", buylist);
```

None but the first line have an effect.

The other possibility is that the code has a bug and what really was meant was this:

```
Vector buylist = session.getAttribute("Register");
if( buylist == null ) {
    buylist = new Vector();
    session.setAttribute("Register", buylist);
}
```

i.e. create a new vector if it doesn't exist already.

Comment: I dont understand one thing, aren't we supposed to set the attribute first and then use the getAttribute method for the session!

How is this code using the "Register" attribute when it has not been defined anywhere, the only way to define the attribute "Register" is to use setAttribue() and then use getAttribute to store it in the session!

Comment: `getAttribute()` will return `null` for unknown attributes. The code you posted only works if someone else has already put the `Register` attribute in the session somewhere. Since you didn't get an NPE, this must have happened.